# Triangle of random variables

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, random-variables

This $3$ random variables
$$
X, \; p(X)=1, \; x \in [0,1],
$$
$$
Y, \; p(Y)=\frac{y}{2}, \; x \in [0,2],
$$
$$
Z, \; p(Z)=\frac{z^2}{9}, \; x \in [0,3].
$$
How to find the probability that three line segments with lengths $X, Y, Z$ we can make a triangle? $p$ -- distribution density.

As I understand it, we need to find the following probability
$$
\mathrm{P}(X+Y \le Z, Y+Z \le X, X+Z \le Y),
$$
but how can it be calculated?

Comment: You're just integrating over that set. draw a picture of that region, and then integrate over it.

Comment: Clarify: all $x$'s in the right side of the equations? Also that $y$ and $z$ dependence in the last one seems potentially problematic. Are you sure it's a PDF?

Comment: How to find the density of the joint distribution?